# Pass date through postman

Tags: java, spring, api, postman, datetime-format

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/checkMeetingRoomAvailability")
public @ResponseBody ResponseDto checkMeetingRoomAvailability(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss") Date begin,
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss") Date end, @RequestParam Integer capacity) {
    return meetingRoomServiceLocal.checkMeetingRoomAvailability(begin, end, capacity);
}
```

when i pass input using postman its giving 400 bad request.

```
meetingRoomController/checkMeetingRoomAvailability?begin=30-9-2020 14:30:00&end=30-9-2020 15:30:00&capacity=10
```

i am unable to figure out why i am getting this error.

Comment: You need to enocde your Request Params. Spaces and hyphens need to be encoded.

Comment: I think you shouldn't have whitespaces in your URL, the error might have to do with your datetime format, which separates the date from the time of day by a whitespace. This is only bad for your URL, not in general...

Comment: As already suggested you should escape whitespaces or use the ISO format to use a 'T' instead of whitespace:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the following solutions will work:

1. **Recommended solution**: Replace `dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss` with `dd-M-yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss` in the code and then you can test it like `meetingRoomController/checkMeetingRoomAvailability?begin=30-9-2020T14:30:00&end=30-9-2020T15:30:00&capacity=10`.
2. Encode the URL so that the space between date and time can be encoded appropriately e.g. as a test, you can encode `meetingRoomController/checkMeetingRoomAvailability?begin=30-9-2020 14:30:00&end=30-9-2020 15:30:00&capacity=10`using some encoding tool e.g. https://www.urlencoder.org/ and use the encoded URL in Postman. I do not recommend this as it will force your clients to encoded URL before they can send a request to your server.